# AngularJS - use a service and controller in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I am trying to use a service and controller in a directive. I have a button directive, on click of the button, i want to call a controller method() and call a service inside that method().

```
AppService.$inject = [];
function AppService() {
    var name = "Name 1";

    function getName() {
      return name;
    }

    function setName(na) {
      name = na;
    }
    return {
      getName : getName,
      setName : setName
    };
}


    AppDirective.$inject = ['appService'];
    function AppDirective(appService) {
    //    var link = function(scope){
    //      scope.showMessage = function(){
    //        alert('you clicked the directive!');
    //      };
    //  };

        var DirectiveController = function($scope) {
            $scope.showMessage = function() {
                /*
        *****        I cannot access the appService here.  ******
                */
                alert('you clicked the directive!');
            };
        };

        return{   
        //link: link,
        template: "<button ng-click='showMessage()'>Button 2</button>",
        controller: DirectiveController    
      };
    }
```

Here is the full plunk
http://plnkr.co/edit/w4UNtZ8CgEsVD0Nt5gqa

But somehow, I am not able to access the service inside the controller of my directive. Please help !!!

Answer (score 3):

You need to inject the dependencies in controller function whenever you want it.

**Code**

```
var DirectiveController = function($scope,appService) {
```

**[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/3u8zf0aTpbLbENNlUsiO?p=preview)**